# Forbid the use of global variables inside a function

Tags: python, scope

Is there any way in Python to **forbid** the use of global variables inside a function?

For example can this:

```
def some_function():
    print(foo)

foo = 'bar'
some_function()
```

instead of printing `bar` be made to raise a `NameError` like:

> NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

Can you limit the variable scope to that of the function (the inner) and deem the global *unreachable*?

Could some kind of decorator or something similar be utilized?

Comment: You could check if `foo` is in `vars()` or `locals()`, but it will force you to use strings ie `'foo'` instead of `foo`

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks for the hint but `some_function` might be a couple of hundred or even more lines of code, so I am looking for something less manual.

Comment: What about global functions? Is it allowed to use those?

Comment: @DeepSpace Nailed it. Thanks!